# How $timeout works in angularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How `$timeout` works in angularJs? And how it's different from `setTimeOut()`?

Comment: I think that's solve my problem. Thanks -@JonKoops

Answer (score 0):

$timeout run a function after a defined delay :

```
$timeout(yourFunction, yourDelayInMS)
```

For sample display an alert after one second:

```
$timeout(function(){alert('hello'},1000);
```

The difference between $timeout against setTimeout is $timeout is a part of the digest cycle of angularjs. if you modify the scope in your code it's better to use $timout instead of setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

for example if you use setTimeout in your link function the $scope variables won't change. Instead you need to do something like that

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
  scope.$apply(function() {
    scope.myVar = "I changed"
  })
},1000);
```

$timeout just wraps that for you.